# Is there a way to specify an input file containing the files to include when creating a zip?

Tags: linux, zip

I have a list of files paths which I am gathering via a script I wrote. These paths are several thousand. Is there a way to have them stored in an input file and then passed into to `zip` when creating the zip?

Comment: Perhaps it should be moved to serverfault, as it's not exactly a programming question, it's related to backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> `-@ file lists`.  If a file list is specified as `-@` [Not on MacOS], `zip` takes the list of input files from standard input instead of from the
>          command line.

So you can do:

```
zip file.zip -@ < file_containing_list_of_paths
```

You don't even need the file, you can pipe directly to `zip`. The example in the man page is:

```
find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope this will work with several thousand paths...

Comment: I would be surprised if there's any limit.